# ASP.NET Processmodel Configuration Optimization

Tags: asp.net, processmodel

A regular ASP.NET installation will create machine.config with the following configuration:

```
<system.web>
    <processModel autoConfig="true" />
```

I would like to override few properties values in web.config like:

```
<system.web>
   <processModel 
     maxWorkerThreads="100" 
     maxIoThreads="100" 
     minWorkerThreads="40" 
     minIoThreads="30" 
     memoryLimit="60" 
   />
```

**I would like to know that whether i have to write all default properties inside web.config or it will automatically take other default properties of processmodel from machine.config?**

Following are the properties of processmodel

```
<processModel 
   enable="true|false"
   timeout="hrs:mins:secs|Infinite" 
   idleTimeout="hrs:mins:secs|Infinite"
   shutdownTimeout="hrs:mins:secs|Infinite"
   requestLimit="num|Infinite"
   requestQueueLimit="num|Infinite"
   restartQueueLimit="num|Infinite"
   memoryLimit="percent"
   webGarden="true|false"
   cpuMask="num"
   userName="{username}"
   password="{secure password}"
   logLevel="All|None|Errors"
   clientConnectedCheck="hrs:mins:secs|Infinite"
   comAuthenticationLevel="Default|None|Connect|Call| 
               Pkt|PktIntegrity|PktPrivacy"
   comImpersonationLevel="Default|Anonymous|Identify|
               Impersonate|Delegate"
   responseDeadlockInterval="hrs:mins:secs|Infinite"
   responseRestartDeadlockInterval="hrs:mins:secs|Infinite"
   autoConfig="true|false"
   maxWorkerThreads="num"
   maxIoThreads="num"
   minWorkerThreads="num"
   minIoThreads="num"
   serverErrorMessageFile="" 
   pingFrequency="Infinite" 
   pingTimeout="Infinite" 
   maxAppDomains="2000"
/>
```

Comment: Ever get an answer to this question?

Answer (score 4):

Machine.config is always inherited.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719558(VS.71).aspx):

> Multiple configuration files, all
>   named Web.config, can appear in
>   multiple directories on an ASP.NET Web
>   application server. Each Web.config
>   file applies configuration settings to
>   its own directory and all child
>   directories below it. Configuration
>   files in child directories can supply
>   configuration information in addition
>   to that inherited from parent
>   directories, and the child directory
>   configuration settings can override or
>   modify settings defined in parent
>   directories. The root configuration
>   file named
>   systemroot\Microsoft.NET\Framework\versionNumber\CONFIG\Machine.config
>   provides ASP.NET configuration
>   settings for the entire Web server.

Comment: Thanks,

Actually i have a doubt; because in machine.config there is only single property "autoConfig="true" but in web.config we are writing specific property name.

If this is confirm that all hidden property is automatically inherited in web.config then it is good.

Comment: That's not how it works. Machine.config and Web.config are merged at runtime, so AutoConfig is either true or false. AutoConfig does not configure inheritance. See more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.processmodelsection.autoconfig(VS.100).aspx

Comment: If you look in machine.config you'll see something like <section name="processModel" allowDefinition="MachineOnly"...> which means you cannot take this advice and set these settings in Web.Config.

Comment: @kamens If you change `allowDefinition` to `MachineToApplication` in `Machine.config` you can. Beware, though, that changes to `processModel` *will require an application pool restart even when* defined in `Web.config`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems we cannot override the processModel settings in web.config as per the below link.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685.aspx

EDIT : I didn't read the comments. We can set MachineToApplication value which requires machine reboot it seems. Any idea what will be the side effects?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Does it make sense to answer the question now? I did a test to change the value, and using the IIS Configuration Manager, I see that the value is updated. Of course the change in on the machine.config file, to it applies to all the sites. I did not find a way to set the value per site.

[image: Default value: 20]

[image: After changing the config]

The machine.config has the following

```
   <processModel autoConfig="false" maxIoThreads="250" />
```

I did not need to set the rest of the values.